# Get HTTP response from server (localhost)

Tags: c#, angular, database, server, httpclient

I am working on an Angular project, in which I want to get a HTTP response from a server database.
What I have so far: a connection to Microsoft SQL Database and a successful response in browser when I run the project through Visual Studio 2019.

This is the JSON data that I get when I call
https://localhost:44311/api/ExampleTable1

```
[
  {
    "firstClm": "bob1      ",
    "secondClm": "1"
  },
  {
    "firstClm": "bob10     ",
    "secondClm": "10"
  },...]
```

In my app.component.html I have:

```
  <button igxButton igxRipple='red' class="text-white" (click)='getPosts()'>
    <span class="text-white"> Get JSON </span>
  </button>

  <div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
    {{ post | json }}
  </div>
```

And in the app.components.ts I have:

```
export class AppComponent {
 // readonly ROOT_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  readonly ROOT_URL = "https://localhost:44311/api/ExampleTable1";
  posts: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPosts() {
    this.posts= this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL);
  }
}
```

When I have https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts as ROOT_URL everything works fine and I can see the JSON data, but if I use https://localhost:44311/api/ExampleTable1 as ROOT_URL nothing happens. If I go to https://localhost:44311/api/ExampleTable1 through the browser, I can see the JSON data.

Why I cannot get the JSON data from my localhost?

P.S. I am working with C# and Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: check browser console, you must be getting CORS error.

Comment: As @AakashGarg wrote, pls. check browser > developer tools > network and post the errors you see or add rxjs error handling and post the errors you get in rxjs error branch.

Answer (score 0):

At first my answer seems unrelated, but you need to be able to see what error you're getting. You should also identify what the Http error code is, in the developer console, under the "Network" tab for the request.

For making the call in Angular, you can get more information by expanding on the following line:

```
 this.posts = this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL);
```

This gives you little choice for displaying and handling errors. Instead, try another form:

```
this.http.get<PostStructure[]>(this.ROOT_URL).subscribe(
data => { 
          this.posts = [...data]; 
        }, 
err => { console.log(err); }, 
() => {}
);
```

You can then use the err variable to learn more information.

Here is a link to the Angular Docs on Http which includes Error handling (where there are even better examples of how to do it):

https://angular.io/guide/http

Also review your browser console, you may be getting a CORS error as the comment suggests.

Comment: There are post describing the code example as not recommended. There's even an eslint rule that will detect the subscribe call in components. Posts recommend to use the async pipe instead and combine it e.g. with the `catchError` operator (as described in the docs you've already linked).

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Agreed, just wanted to get him to an error message and point him to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```
this.posts$ = this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL);
```

in your html

```
<button igxButton igxRipple='red' class="text-white" (click)='getPosts()'>
    <span class="text-white"> Get JSON </span>
  </button>

  <div *ngFor="let post of (posts$ | async)">
    {{ post | json }}
  </div>
```